# Layoutproblem with webview and buttons

Tags: android, layout, screen

I have a layout problem and don't know how to solve it.

I like to display a webview and 2 buttons on the screen.
I defined this with a LinearLayout containing the webview and another linearlayout, which holds the 2 buttons.

This looked very good so far. Since the newer devices have larger screensizes , my screen looks very ugly
because my buttons are too small. 
The inner linearlayout which holds the 2 buttons is defined with layout_height="60px", which I guess is my problem.

How would you manage this to look good on any device ? Is there a possibility to define sizes depending on the screensize ?
Or should I set the height of my inner linearlayout at runtime as a factor of screenheigh ?

What is the best way to do this ?

regards

Screenshot showing my buttons are too small on HD screen.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:id="@+id/textviewerlayout"
android:orientation="vertical">


<WebView 
        android:id="@+id/mywebview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    />

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="60px"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:id="@+id/textviewerbuttonlayout"
android:orientation="horizontal">
 <Button
      android:id="@+id/vorher"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0"
      android:text="" />
 <Button
      android:id="@+id/nachher"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0"
      android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jorgan said use dp than the px.

Take a look if it this is what are looking for:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mywebview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textviewerbuttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vorher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nachher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Using weight to determine height is gonna make it look good in any size, but if you want to make a specific layout for tablet or land scape you should make it in  theirs folders.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand why you use android:layout_height="0dp". Should that be android:layout_height="60dp" in my case ?

Comment: No it should be 0 because I'm using the weight to define it height.

Comment: if you define that android:layout_height="60dp" , it gonna be ok in a galaxy Y for example, but in a tablet it should be very small

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for the explanation. After 2 years Android programming I only yesterday understood the weight feature :-). So simple.

Answer (score 2):

Rather then using px, use dp. This will use density-independent pixels which are calculated per device based on the screen size and resolution. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) for more info. Because HD screens use higher density pixels, your buttons will appear smaller due to their hardcoded pixel size. Using dp (or dip) will make them approximately the same size across multiple devices.

Comment: Thank you. So I try to use android:layout_height="60dp".

Comment: 60dp may or may not look right. The key thing is to use dp, then you can adjust the number accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Check the above link under the topic Best practices

Here is a quick checklist about how you can ensure that your application displays properly on different screens:

1. Use wrap_content, fill_parent, or dp units when specifying dimensions in an XML layout file.
2. Do not use hard coded pixel values in your application code

You can use a single  relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/mywebview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"  
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="67dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
        android:text="Button" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```